# Populating Excel Sheets from Access like an Access Report

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am hoping to create multiple excel sheets from data imported into an access database. 
Information from the database would only affect particular sections of the excel sheet and I was wondering if there is a similar way of populating it like the reports (i.e. specifying general sections where it would be populated).

Alternatively, would there be a way of saving the reports into files (that could be edited) to be printed out later?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either export your recordsets (the excel files you are exporting) to PDF or create reports (and then export them) using Access Report built in function.